# Android: Filling ListView with file system folders and files. Performance choices

Tags: android, listview, directory

I'm developing some kind of Music Player. 
I'm trying to improve the file browsing part. That functionallity is already implemented, and it is the following:
The user is able to navigate through the file system, and see all the music files in every folder. It is also possible to search any string, and the app will show music files contained in the current folder.

The implementation details are the following:
A custom SimpleAdapter is feeded with the child folders and files of the current directory and the adapter in turn, feeds the ListView which is shown in the screen. I also exclude not-music files and not-containing-music-folders so they do not show up. When the user presses in any of those folders (or the parent folder), then the ListView adapter is cleared and feeded again with the folders and files contained in the new location directory. This is done by creating a new File object for the new location folder, calling listFiles() and so.
The search functionallity is implemented by making the ListAdapter implements Filterable interface and using getFilter() method. On every change of the searchbar (which is an EditText), the adapters gets filtered with the written string. For that purpose I use two different adapters, one is the original and the other one is the filtered one.
I think I made it clear.

Implementation details aside, I would like to know which are the implementation alternatives for the functionallity I described. 
The performance of my implementation is not good enough. When the user is located in a folder with many folders and files, moving back and forward through directories is slow. Besides, I do use two different adapters for the searching purpose, which limitates the behavior and also implies so many inconsistencies.

I was thinking about this alternative of storing the file system structure as a tree structure in a XML file, so I would avoid the file calculation and not-music-file exclusion costs on every location change. It would load the XML tree instead. Also, search filtering would be easier and more consistent.
However, I could not find any thread about this. So maybe it's not as good idea as I think.

What do you think?
Thank you.